# USing a Scanner Import

Tags: python, loops, command-line

Say a file contains as set of records, and the first line of the record is:

```
@ 2014 2 14 00:03:01 Matt "login" 0.01
```

I'm trying to print that entire first line then come back and loop the rest of the remaining files which I could do perfectly fine, But I was recently just informed that our teacher wants us to use a scanner import, and basically what a scanner is, is  a reading subsystem that allows you to read whitespace-delimited tokens from a file. I'm pretty much confused on how a scanner can be used to read single lines at a time... any help on Scanners would be great

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scanner/ maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lexical scanner in python standard library which is called tokenize: http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html

You have to pass a parameter which is a function used by the scanner to read a line, thus interfacing with any kind of input (string, file,...).

(read first line)

```
with file("...", 'r') as f:
    g = generate_tokens(f.readline())
```

or (whole file)

```
with file("...", 'r') as f:
    g = generate_tokens(f.read())
```

or (line by line)

```
with file("...", 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        g = generate_tokens(StringIO(l).readline)
```

should do the trick.

You can go back to the begining of the file using f.seek(0)